# IPA segment for a sentence in American English

Tags: ipa, transcription

Could someone please help me out with the IPA segments for the phrase "Critical Equipment needs proper maintenance"? There have been varying answers and I'd like to know if I'm on the right track.

Thank you

Comment: There are a _lot_ of American English dialects (and a decent amount of variation even within "General American"), and a lot of different conventions for transcription (do you treat schwa as its own phoneme? do you use syllabic resonants?). Multiple linguists are unlikely to give exactly the same transcription for anything.

Answer (score 1):

In principle it is possible if you have a recording of the utterance, and as long as you understand that there can be no departure from a narrow phonetic transcription of that utterance (i.e. this can't be a phonemic transcription). Even then, transcriptional choices are not uniquely predetermined by the nature of the IPA, so there will always be some degree of uncertainty as to the transcription.
Moreover, since this is no doubt a homework assignment, you would have to provide your solution for us to comment on. In light of all of that, I think the answer is "no, it is not possible".